# Add repository from Gradle plugin

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

I am writing a Gradle plugin, and I would like it to add repositories to the project.

How can I do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside the `apply` method of your `Plugin<Project>` class, add the following:

- for Maven Central: `project.repositories.mavenCentral()`
- for Google Maven: `project.repositories.maven()`

More generally, call any function that you would place in the `repositories` section of your build script from `project.repositories`.

You can find entire list of such functions here: https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.dsl.RepositoryHandler.html